# How to upload .jtl file to blazemeter sense

Tags: windows, jenkins, jmeter, blazemeter

I created a Jenkins job where it run some JMeter scripts and return .jtl files. Now, I want to upload this files to Blazemeter Sense to see the performance test, downloads pdf reports, etc.
I've searched a lot of information, where I find that to upload some file, I can use this command thats running from Windows CMD:

`curl -v https://sense.blazemeter.com/api/files -H "Authorization: Token 'cat ~/.loadosophia.token'" -F "projectKey=Project_name" -F "jtl_file=@jtl.gz"`

REFERENCE: https://sense.blazemeter.com/wiki/help:uploads/

The only values that I change are

- `cat ~/.loadosophia.token`, where I replaced for my Upload Token (finded in Blazemeter Sense -> Options -> Settings ->   Your Upload Token)
  [image]
- `projectKey` where I replaced by my project name (test_taurus)
  [image]
- `jtl_file` where I replaced by the file directory generated by Jmeter test (.jtl)

The final command is:

`curl -v https://sense.blazemeter.com/api/files -H "Authorization: Token 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXYLaa'" -F "projectKey=test_taurus" -F "jtl_file=/path/of/file/file.jtl"`

I missed some? What is my wrong? Existe another posibility to make it?

Thanks everyone

**U P D A T E**:

I did what Dmitri T said. Thats works. But when I run the command, the output is the following:

[image]

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to remove quotation marks around the token
2. You need to add an "at" symbol before the .jtl file path

   Fixed command would be something like:

   ```
   curl -v https://sense.blazemeter.com/api/files -H "Authorization: Token XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXYLaa" -F "projectKey=test_taurus" -F "jtl_file=@/path/of/file/file.jtl"
   ```

More information: [Upload files with CURL](https://medium.com/@petehouston/upload-files-with-curl-93064dcccc76)

---

You might find [BM.Sense Uploader](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/sense-uploader/LoadosophiaUploader.md) plugin more convenient to use, the plugin can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager):

[image: JMeter BlazeMeter Uploader Plugin]

Comment: Hi @Dmitri T! I edit according your response, but the output is `Warning: setting file /path/of/file/file.jtl
Warning: failed!`. But when I upload this file manually, its work without errors. I need to does it from command line. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Dear Carlos, have you tried to substitute `/path/of/file/file.jtl` with **real** and **full** path to your .jtl results file?

Comment: Dmitri, maybe this error is because I running curl command from Windows CMD? So I dont know how to solve if the problem is for that. Sorry, I forget it, I update the question with that fact!

Comment: Ya, I did that. Im running the command with the full path of the file

Comment: Since when paths in Windows start with a backslash?

Comment: I deleted the backslash between "at" symbol and C: "jtl_file=@C:\JMeter\Rendimiento\Personas\pruebas_taurus\%nombre_jtl%.jtl". Thanks Dmitri T :)