# Upload Local File by Using CURL Command in Shared Library Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to upload a file from a local directory to a remote directory. I have a Groovy library that I have written to do this.

```
def file = "$WORKPLACE/**/*-${BUILD_NUMBER}-*/file.txt"

pulic uploadArtifct (String user, String password, String file, String 
  location) {
  def cred = "${user}:${password}"
  def cmd = ["curl", "-v", "-u", cred, "-F", "files=@${file}", ${location}]
  try {
   def sout = new StringBuffer(), serr = new StringBuffer()
   def proc = cmd.execute()
   proc.consumeProcessOutput(sout, serr)
   proc.waitForOrKill(1000)
   println sout
  } catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeExceptipon("Cannot execute curl, exception: [${e.getClass().getName()} - '${e.getMessage()}']")
   }
  }
```

However, the above fails with the error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot execute curl, exception: [java.lang.RuntimeException - 'Error running ; stdout='', stderr='warning:setting file 
Warning: /app/jenkins/workspace/Job/**/*-10-*/file.txt 
Warning: failed!
```

How do I make sure that the file is set correctly? Also is the `-F` approach correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error message

```
Cannot execute curl, exception: [java.lang.RuntimeException - 'Error running ; stdout='', stderr='warning:setting file 
Warning: /app/jenkins/workspace/Job/**/*-10-*/file.txt 
Warning: failed!
```

was seen in [another context](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51307393/6309)

The path needs an "at" (`@`) symbol before the .jtl file path

```
-F "jtl_file=@/path/to/file"
```

In your case, the double-quotes might be missing.

```
"\"files=@${file}\""
```

Comment: @SSF You are welcome. I have reported the "double-quotes" requirement in my answer of your previous question.